# To search for .zip files inside of a download.log,

Tags: regex, grep, posix

I am struggling with an assignment.

This is the assignment: Collect specific entries from file or pipe by regular expression or simple text search
- from download.log, get all zip file names and their size. Put the output into a new file.

I tried to tackle this problem with grep.

This is what I got so far:
`grep -E -w '......*|.zip' download.log`
Executing this command just gives me the entire `download.log`

Does anyone have ideas how to tackle this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a good place to try different patterns to see what they are actually doing.

Comment: Provide a sample log to work with, as it depends on the format. Simplest version would be something like this: [`.*?\.zip`](https://regex101.com/r/6tbzWB/2)

Comment: `2017-06-13 01:24:08,805 INFO:ciq_ftp_download: FinancialsAdjustedChange20170612.zip downloaded successfully. Total size: 0.0 MB. Average speed: 0.0 MB/s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should work for you: 
`grep -E '\S*.zip' download.log`

`\S` means that we search for non-whitespace character. Meaning alphanumeric characters, hyphen, dot or underline followed by `.zip`

If you want grep to only output the matches simply use the `-o` option additionally.